# Como saber qual classe de link selecionar com php

Tags: php, mysql, classes, php-domdocument

Estou criando um site que possui informações de vários vendedores acessadas por um administrador. Para exibir os dados dos vendedores, disponho os nomes deles numa tabela, selecionando-os de um banco de dados MySQL.

Pegando os dados:

```
$db = mysqli_connect($servername, $user_db, $pass_db, $nome_db) or die(mysqli_error());
    mysqli_select_db($db, $nome_db);
    $query_vendor = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID != 4";//id temporária do admin
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query_vendor);
    $vendorData = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

Disposição dos nomes dos vendedores:

```
<?php
      do{
           echo "<tr><td><a href='vendorData.php' target='_blank' class='$vendorData[ID]'>$vendorData[USERNAME]</a></td></tr>";
          }while($vendorData = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
 ?>
```

Na página que encaminho todos os vendedores, a vendorData.php, preciso mostrar o nome do vendedor cujo link foi clicado. **Minha dúvida é**: como vou saber qual link foi clicado? Sei que posso pegar a classe dos links com o [DOM Document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) (seguindo essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366351/getting-dom-elements-by-classname)), mas não sei como definir o valor da variável `$classname` para pegar a classe certa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você irá passar por parâmetro para a outra página, através do protocolo `http` `GET`, insira no `href`o seguinte ajuste para passar como parâmetro:

```php
<?php
      do{
           echo "<tr><td><a href='vendorData.php?id=".$vendorData[ID]."' target='_blank' class='$vendorData[ID]'>$vendorData[USERNAME]</a></td></tr>";
          }while($vendorData = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
 ?>
```

Na página `vendorData.php` capture o id da seguinte maneira:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Esse array irá trazer todos os parâmetros passados através do protocolo `http get`.

Comment: Obrigada, deu certo!